# Sibling div not showing with 100% height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a swipeable menu and it is working except for one aspect. I want the menu to have a height of 100% at all times..no matter how far down the user has scrolled on the page. However, whenever I set it to `height: 100%;` the menu will not swipe over. It only seems to work when the height is set to `height: 100vh`, but as you will see in my fiddle, this pushed the `#main` div down the screen. I am wanting the main div to be at the very top and for the menu to open up over it.

Please note, you have to swipe to the left to open the menu:

[You can see the example here](https://jsfiddle.net/43kjns4d/5/)

I am wanting it to open like this:

[image]

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
div.box-parent {
  height: 100vh;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}
div.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #108040;
  margin-left: -101%;
}
div.box.swipeleft {
  background: #7ACEF4;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
#main {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

```
$(function(){
  $( "body" ).on( "swiperight", swiperightHandler );

  function swiperightHandler( event ){
    $('.nav-panel').addClass( "swiperight" );
  }
});
$(function(){
  $( "body" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );

  function swipeleftHandler( event ){
    $('.nav-panel').addClass( "swipeleft" );
  }
});
$.mobile.loading().hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not detect the swipe on the `body` and give the `.box` a `fixed` position.

```js
$(function(){
  $("body").on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );
  
  function swipeleftHandler( event ){
    $('#box').addClass( "swipeleft" );
  }
  
});

$.mobile.loading().hide();
```

```css
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; min-height:100%;}
 #box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #108040;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    left:100%;
  }
  #box.swipeleft {
    background: #7ACEF4;
    left: 50%;
  }
  #main {
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Or as a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43kjns4d/7/)

Comment: @Paul it works but `.nav-panel` is _behind_ the other content. It just needs a `z-index` greater than the main content. Add `.nav-panel {z-index:10;}` and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks so much for checking! I really appreciate it
!

Comment: Do you know why when I added more javascript to be able to close this with a swipe, why this only works once? What I mean is I can swipeleft and swiperight once, but then after it will not continue to swipe.

Comment: By the way, I added the new javascript to my question.

Comment: I imagine because you're giving the `.nav-panel` _both_ swipeleft and swiperight classes. On swiperight you should just _remove_ the swipeleft class. EG `$('.nav-panel').removeClass( "swipeleft");`

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up your code a bit to remove some unnecessary elements and styles. This is better accomplished using `position: absolute;`, so the menu overlaps your content and isn't part of the document flow.

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ua7q6uks/

Comment: The thing is, the nav (box-parent) needs to be a sibling element with main.

Comment: @Paul Is there a particular reason for that? If that's the case, `.box-parent` will always be overlapping `#main` and intercepting any clicks, preventing you from interacting with content in `#main`. Typically slideout menus are in the same parent container as content.

Comment: `#main` is just a section of content. My menu is a fixed element on my page in a destop viewport. I then have different section all the way down the page. The menu cannot be just in the one section. This is more of what the page is actually like https://jsfiddle.net/43kjns4d/6/.

Comment: @Paul Here's the proper way to do it, then: https://jsfiddle.net/wkooLtdt/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but a slightly different approach that might work:

```
.box-parent
{
position:relative;
}

.box
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0
right: /*fixed width here; try 50% */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully functional one, where JS swipeleft and swiperight show and hide the div, respectively. These are executed on html and .box has fixed positioning.
Also cleaned up a bit and added a transition for looks.

https://jsfiddle.net/ZheerH/43kjns4d/13/

```js
$(function(){

$( 'html' ).on( "swipeleft", function() { 
$('.box').addClass( "swipeleft" );
});

$( 'html' ).on( "swiperight", function() { 
$('.box').removeClass( "swipeleft" );
});

});

$.mobile.loading().hide();
```

```css
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div.box {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: lightblue;
    position:fixed;
    left:100vw;
    top:0;
    z-index:999;
    transition:left 0.6s ease;
 }
 div.box.swipeleft {
    left:50vw;
 }
 #main {
    height: 800px;
    width: 100vw;
    background: green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>

<div id="main"></div>
```